# javascript multiple regex matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string below

> [NeMo (PROD)] 10.10.100.100 (EFA-B-3) [Brocade FC-Switch ] Sensor:
>   Power Supply #1 (SNMP Custom Table) Down  (No Such Name (SNMP error #
>   2))

I try to get multiple matches to extract the following values:

```
var system = "PROD";
var ip = "10.10.100.100";
var location = "EFA-B-3";
var device = "Brocade FC-Switch";
var sensor = "Sensor: Power Supply #1";
var sensorArt = "SNMP Custom Table";
var sensorState = "Down";
var errorMsg = "No Such Name (SNMP error # 2)";
```

Since I am a beginner with regex I tried to define some "rules":

1. Extract first value within the first round brackets e.g **PROD**
2. Extract the value between the first closing square bracket and
   second opening round bracket e.g. **10.10.100.100**
3. Extract the value within the second round brackets e.g **EFA-B-3**
4. Extract the value within the second square brackets e.g. **Brocade
   FC-Switch**
5. Extract the value between the second closing square bracket and the
   third opening round bracket e.g. **Sensor: Power Supply #1**
6. Extract the value given within the third round brackets e.g. **SNMP
   Custom Table**
7. Extract the value between the third closing round bracket and the
   fourth opening round bracket e.g. **Down**
8. Extract the value within the fourth round brackets e.g. **No Such Name
   (SNMP error # 2)**

Using the webpage https://scriptular.com/ I tried to achieve my goal.
So far I managed to build the regex

> (?=(([^)]+)))

which gives me my first match (rule 1). Somehow I fail to declare the regex to look between the brackets. What am I missing?

Comment: `let [_, system, ip, location, device, sensor, sensorArt, sensorState, errorMsg] = s.match(/\(([^()]+)\)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]*)\)\s*\[([^\][]*)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)/)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are a beast, its working great. Thanks for the example, I try to learn from it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no way to define separators, the only way is to match the parts and capture them separately.

```
/\(([^()]+)\)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]*)\)\s*\[([^\][]*)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLkixZ/1).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]+)` - Group 1: 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)]\s*` - `)]` and 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*\(` - 0+ whitespaces, `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 3: 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)\s*\[` - `)`, 0+ whitespaces, `[`
- `([^\][]*)` - Group 4: 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\s*` - `]` and 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 5: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*\(` - 0+ whitespaces, `(`
- `([^()]+)` - Group 6: 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)\s*` - `)` and 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 7: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*\(` - 0+ whitespaces and `(`
- `(.*)` - Group 8: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as *many* as possible
- `\)` - `)` char.

ES6+ code snippet:

```js
var s = "[NeMo (PROD)] 10.10.100.100 (EFA-B-3) [Brocade FC-Switch ] Sensor: Power Supply #1 (SNMP Custom Table) Down (No Such Name (SNMP error # 2))";
let [_, system, ip, location1, device, sensor, sensorArt, sensorState, errorMsg] = s.match(/\(([^()]+)\)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]*)\)\s*\[([^\][]*)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)/);
console.log(`System=${system}\nIP=${ip}\nLocation=${location1}\nDevice=${device}\nSensor=${sensor}\nSensorArt=${sensorArt}\nSensorState=${sensorState}\nErrorMsg=${errorMsg}`);
```

ES5:

```js
var s = "[NeMo (PROD)] 10.10.100.100 (EFA-B-3) [Brocade FC-Switch ] Sensor: Power Supply #1 (SNMP Custom Table) Down (No Such Name (SNMP error # 2))";
var system, ip, location1, device, sensor, sensorArt, sensorState, errorMsg;
var rx = /\(([^()]+)\)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]*)\)\s*\[([^\][]*)]\s*(.*?)\s*\(([^()]+)\)\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)/;
if (m = s.match(rx)) {
  system = m[1];
  ip = m[2];
  location1=m[3];
  device=m[4];
  sensor=m[5];
  sensorArt=m[6];
  sensorState=m[7];
  errorMsg=m[8];
}
console.log("System="+system+"\nIP="+ip+"\nLocation="+location1+"\nDevice="+device+"\nSensor="+sensor+"\nSensorArt="+sensorArt+"\nSensorState="+sensorState+"\nErrorMsg="+errorMsg);
```